# Can "comprised" be used as a verb in this instance?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, tenses

A co-worker of mine posted an article he wrote in which he used the sentence,  "The majority of terminals and buildings that once *comprised* the airport are literally in rubble."

Having never seen this before, it didn't sound right to me. Of course, he can't possibly say *comprised of* in this instance. Would it be more correct for him to have written, "The majority of terminals and buildings that the airport was *comprised of* are literally in rubble"? (on a side-note, I've also read that *comprised of* is redundant)

I guess what I'm getting at is can *comprised* be used as a verb?

Comment: For reasons that aren’t clear to me, this phraseology is far less common than using “composed”. However, it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it can. In fact it's the first example [here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/comprised). I don't think it's common to hear in every day speech, but it is valid.